# Why is <taglib> giving me a problem in my web.xml?

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I have this web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>jsp-tags</display-name>
     <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>mytags</taglib-uri>
       <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/mytaglib.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

The  is highlighted and the error the IDE gives is: "Invalid content was found starting with element  ...

What more do I need to do?

Comment: What more do you need to do? You need to accept @Jaydeep's answer. :-P

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use this notation:

```
<jsp-config> 
        <taglib> 
               <taglib-uri>mytags</taglib-uri> 
               <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/jsp/mytaglib.tld</taglib-location> 
        </taglib> 
</jsp-config>
```

But I recommended to read this [link](http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/RemovingTaglibFromWeb.xml). This tutorial will give you idea how to avoid declaring taglibs in web.xml in case of JSP 2.0

Answer (score 7):

In the XSD referenced in your XML, it states that for complex type web-appType you can only have a choice of zero to many of the following elements:

```
<xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xsd:group ref="javaee:descriptionGroup"/>
  <xsd:element name="distributable"
 type="javaee:emptyType"/>
  <xsd:element name="context-param"
 type="javaee:param-valueType">

  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="filter"
 type="javaee:filterType"/>
  <xsd:element name="filter-mapping"
 type="javaee:filter-mappingType"/>
  <xsd:element name="listener"
 type="javaee:listenerType"/>
  <xsd:element name="servlet"
 type="javaee:servletType"/>
  <xsd:element name="servlet-mapping"
 type="javaee:servlet-mappingType"/>
  <xsd:element name="session-config"
 type="javaee:session-configType"/>
  <xsd:element name="mime-mapping"
 type="javaee:mime-mappingType"/>
  <xsd:element name="welcome-file-list"
 type="javaee:welcome-file-listType"/>
  <xsd:element name="error-page"
 type="javaee:error-pageType"/>
  <xsd:element name="jsp-config"
 type="javaee:jsp-configType"/>
  <xsd:element name="security-constraint"
 type="javaee:security-constraintType"/>
  <xsd:element name="login-config"
 type="javaee:login-configType"/>
  <xsd:element name="security-role"
 type="javaee:security-roleType"/>
  <xsd:group ref="javaee:jndiEnvironmentRefsGroup"/>
  <xsd:element name="message-destination"
 type="javaee:message-destinationType"/>
  <xsd:element name="locale-encoding-mapping-list"
 type="javaee:locale-encoding-mapping-listType"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

The taglib element is not referenced in the XSD at all.

From reading [this link](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/04/24/how-to-reference-and-use-jstl-in-your-web-application/) it would seem that you do not need to declare taglibs in the web-app document. Simply having the version="2.5" attribute means you can reference tags in your JSPs.

Answer (score -1):

If the taglib is inside of a **maven dependency,** just set the scope to compile.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
     <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.10</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```