# can not find the tag library descriptor for struts2

Tags: struts2, struts, taglib

I encounter the error `"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'taglib'."`. Check the answer in [TagLib tag in web.xml is not found ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022189/taglib-tag-in-web-xml-is-not-found-error) ,I comment the `"taglib"` part in `web.xml`

but another problem occured, `"can not find the tag library descriptor for struts2"`. I tried to find some way to solve it, like [Cannot find the tag library descriptor for /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld in Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374311/cannot-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-web-inf-struts-html-tld-in-struts), I move `"struts-tags.tld"` up to `WEB-INF` folder, but it didn't work.

I don't really understand this issue, it seems that there are something wrong with my struts, feeling puzzled... I would be appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you included the version, what you're deploying, and a minimal JSP example that reproduces the error. You do not need to include anything in `web.xml` (that requirement went away *years* ago) and should only need the Struts 2 distribution deployed.

Comment: Did you include Struts 2 core jar file and reference tag lib in jsp using jsp directive?