# <jsp-property-group> not working with <taglib> tag

Tags: jsf, weblogic12c

I am working on a JSF application where I have need of creating a custom taglib.
I need to create some function which will be used inside el expression tag in my jsf page.

Please find below my taglib file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD FaceletTaglib 1.0//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
  <facelet-taglib >
   <namespace>http://com.xyz/functions</namespace>

   <function>
      <function-name>customMethodName</function-name>
      <function-class>Custom JavaClass</function-class>
       <function-signature>String customMethodName(java.lang.String) 
      </function-signature>
   </function>
 </facelet-taglib>
```

In web.xml at first I defined this in following way:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/taglib/mytaglib.taglib.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

But it was not sufficient during compile time it couldn't identify the URI.

In jsf page it was included as:

```
xmlns:csfn="http://com.xyz/functions"
<h:outputText value="#{csfn:customMethodName(data)}">
```

There after I made following modification::

```
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<jsp-config>
   <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
      <is-xml>true</is-xml>
  </jsp-property-group>
  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://com.xyz/functions</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/taglib/mytaglib.taglib.xml</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
 </jsp-config>
 </web-app>
```

This time application got compiled successfully but having error during deployment in weblogic 12.2.1

```
    Unable to access the selected application.
    Message icon - Error VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND <372:7> problem: 
    cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'jsp-property-group@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 
   'taglib@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' here in element jsp- config@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    Message icon - Error VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND <372:7> problem: 
    cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected element 'jsp-property-group@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' instead of 
  'taglib@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' here in element jsp- config@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
```

Can anyone figure out the problem???

Comment: Well, I didn't test anything, but the error is saying that `<taglib>` should not be part of `<jsp-config>`.

Comment: You're going to do better with `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is <taglib> giving me a problem in my web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775264/why-is-taglib-giving-me-a-problem-in-my-web-xml)

Comment: I have already tried that using <jsp-config> but still it gave the error.@Nicholas.